# Invoke function from div with angularJS parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below I'm attempting to convert millisecond to javascript date :

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            parseDate({{test}})
        </script>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.test = "1429831430363"
}

function parseDate(date) {
    var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                  'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

    return months[date.getUTCMonth()] + ' ' + date.getUTCDate();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15141/

But error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` is thrown on console.

What is correct method of invoking function from div with angularJS parameter ?

Comment: Just create `parseDate` inside `controller` as `$scope.parseDate` and call is `<div>{{ parseDate(test) }} </div>`

Comment: why can't delegate it to a function in the angular controlle..... your script is ailing because the script syntax is wrong

Comment: do you want to access scope variable inside your javascript function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this code : see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15151/)

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <div>
      {{parseDate(test)}}
      </div>
  </div>
</div>


function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.test = "1429831430363"

    $scope.parseDate=function(date) {
    var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                  'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

    return months[(new Date()).getUTCMonth()] + ' ' + (new Date()).getUTCDate();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant solution to format a date is creating a custom filter because is more clean and you can re-use it everywhere:

Filter:

```
myApp.filter('myMillisecondsToUTCDate', [function() {
    return function(milliseconds) {
        var date = new Date(milliseconds);
        var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                      'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
        return months[date.getUTCMonth()] + ' ' + date.getUTCDate();
    };
}]);
```

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.testDate = 1429831430363;   
    // Re-Use the filter everywhere
    $scope.formattedDate = $filter('myMillisecondsToUTCDate')($scope.testDate);
});
```

Html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Format a date using a custom filter: {{testDate | myMillisecondsToUTCDate}}<br/>
    Formatted date {{formattedDate}}
</div>
```

[Check the demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manzapanza/0ovpL97p/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `angular.element` and `jqLite.scope` to get the scope object. Remember that angular and your app need to be initialized for this to work, so you'd better call `parseDate` in a callback.

```
parseDate(
  angular
    .element('[ng-controller="TodoCtrl"]') // but you'd rather give it an ID / class name / whatever
    .scope()
    .test
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modififying your code:

1. We dont need script inside divs as they are still evaluated seperately.
2. defined parseDate inside angularjs controller,  If this is really general, define it as a service/factory and use it everywhere. That is the angular way.
3. Your test is a string. It doesnot have getUTCMonth function, it should be a number so that it can be converted to a date so that we can use the above function.

following is the modified code, which works:

```
    <div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <div>
            {{parseDate(test)}}
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the controller:

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.test = 1429831430363;
  $scope.parseDate = function(date) {
  var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
  date = new Date(date);
  return months[date.getUTCMonth()] + ' ' + date.getUTCDate();
}
}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15146/